# Flash not working in Chrome on Windows laptop

Tags: windows, google-chrome, flash

[image]

Flash is not working on our laptops. we have looked for solutions and found the following:

1. Go to chrome settings
2. Go to advanced to content flash settings
3. Add the sites you wish to enable flash

the above screenshot shows there is no add button available.

I have tried to reinstall chrome to see if this solves the issue, but it doesn't

Can someone please advise how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

The way this works in Chrome is to open a website containing Flash. Chrome will ask you to click to enable the Flash app. This action will then add the site to the list of Allowed Sites.

It *is* possible to remove sites from this list through the settings menu.